# Elementary Union of Sets Question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I have a ton of questions about elementary set theory.  Here's one that stumped me just now.

The task is to give an example of sets A and B for which $\cup A = \cup B$ but $A\neq B$.

Here's my guess:

A = {a,{b,c}}

B = {{a,b},c}

∪A = {a,b,c} = ∪B

Is this true, or, on the other hand, is ∪A = {a,{b,c}}, requiring some other solution?

Thank you.  All of my set theory practice exercises are from the book **Elements of Set Theory** by Herbert B. Enderton

Comment: What does this $\cup A$ mean? Not familiar with this term.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta It's the union of all elements of a set. It's pretty standard in every set theory text I've read.

Comment: @Connor $\bigcup A=\bigcup a\cup\{b,c\}\neq\bigcup c\cup\{a,b\}=\bigcup B$.

Comment: Union of all elements of a set is of course the set itself.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta : The notation $\cup A$ refers to what many mathematicians (who are only _using_ set theory rather than _doing_ set theory) would call $\displaystyle \bigcup_{x\,\in\,A} x. \qquad$

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta : Suppose $A= \{a,b\}$ and $a=\{1,2\}$ and $b=\{2,3\}$ Then $$ \cup A = \{1,2\}\cup\{2,3\} = \{1,2,3\} \ne A. $$ The set $A$ has exactly two members; the set $\cup A$ has three. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy oh, thanks a lot. Understood.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta No, it's the union of the elements $\{a\},\{b,c\}$. $\{a\}\cup\{b,c\}=\{a,b,c\}$

Answer (score 6):

If $A = \{\{a\},\{b,c\}\}$ and $B=\{\{a,b\},\{c\}\}$ then $\cup A = \cup B = \{a,b,c\}.$

But if $A=\{a,\{b,c\}\}$ then the **members** of $a$ are members of $\cup A.$ And you haven't said what the members of $a$ are.

Comment: Thanks, this sort of answers my question because you have shown under what circumstances the union of A = union of B.  However, are you saying that the equality may no longer hold if ∃X | X ∈ a ?

Comment: I haven't said that any particular equality I've mentioned may no longer hold under some circumstances.  You should observe that $A = \{\{a\},\{b,c\}\}$ is not the same as $A = \{a,\{b,c\}\}.$ If, for example, $a=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ then every one of $0,1,2,3,\ldots$ is a member of $\cup A.$ But if $A=\{\{a\},\{b,c\}\},$ then $\cup A$ has only three members. $\qquad$